# Add delay of Cypress auto-running of test on watch

Tags: cypress

My dev workflow includes nodemon and webpack, both on watch, which get triggered whenever there is a change in relevant files. I've recently added Cypress to the project, and noticed that it reruns its test too when relevant files are changed. However with my local dev, there is a delay of a few seconds, when the website goes offline while it updates. So, Cypress is unable to connect with the site when it retriggers at that time. Is there any way to put an elegant delay only on these Cypress reruns?